# Want option to have my profile default to Activity Tab

Tags: feature-request

I dislike the new Profile format. Some people love it and I'm happy for them. I have no illusions about going back to the old format that made sense to me.

My Profile tab feels like a hot mess. I couldn't come up with one or 2 suggestions to make it better. Just don't ever want it.

The activity tab is less bad. At least it's organized and has the important data.

Being able to set Activity to be my Default view takes some of the bad taste out of the new look.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to make *your* profile default to Activity for everybody who visits, or for a way to you to see *other's* Activity tabs instead of Profile tabs when you visit them?

Comment: Yes, I am asking to my profile to default to Activity for anyone who sees it instead of Profile View.

Comment: Your profile goes to your profile tab but mine goes to my activity tab. Why? I actually want mine to go to my profile tab (unlike you).

Comment: @Xonatron, for your profile a cookie or localstore is set to remember the last tab used.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich, so it defaults to the activity tab for me, but stores the last tab used via cookie for each user? How can I change the default tab?

Comment: @Xonatron, The profile page seems to store your last viewed mode of seeing your own profile. At least that's how it works for me. When I look at anyone else's profile, it always defaults to "Profile" View. I don't think there is any way to change that. Does it work differently for you? Does yours always go to "Activity" even if your last visit was to Profile view?